# How do I create an iterable collection of object instances in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a list of `myObject` Type, When I add an object instance via `list.add` then passing the constructor for `myObject`, the first property I can reference, subsequent properties are null.

```
// my class and its constructor method

class Channel {
  final String channelName;
  final String channelDesc;
  final String channelEvent;
  final String channelThumbLink;

  const Channel(this.channelName, this.channelDesc, this.channelEvent,
      this.channelThumbLink);
}

// I construct a list of type<Channel>

final List<Channel> channelList = <Channel>[]
    ..add(Channel(
        'Funkycooking',
        'Welcome to the Funkycooking channel, we cook, you get funky',
        'Sizzling Salsa Saturday!',
        '1'))

// Referencing these elements from the list collection in any widget

Text('${channelList[0].channelName}'),
Text('${channelList[0].channelDesc}'),
```

`Text('${channelList[0].channelName}')` returns 'Funkycooking' as expected

`Text('${channelList[0].channelDesc}')` returns null, i would expect 'Welcome to the Funkycooking channel, we cook, you get funky'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I had assumed incorrectly that hot reload would correctly reflect my object coding changes, it did not, but by stopping and restarting the app, it behaves as I had expected.